# Is there any way to get a model ID trough a form?

Tags: python, django, view

I'm trying that when you upload some image trough a django form, in the view you can get the object and redirect to the image's url.

I have tried to include an id field into the ModelForm, but its not working. Here is the view that handles the POST.

```
def model_form_upload(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('index') 
            # here i want to redirect something like /media/image1.jgp
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
    return render(request, 'src/model_form_upload.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, in fact if you call `form.save()` on a `ModelForm` it will *return* the *instance* it created/modified, so you can just obtain the instance and extract attributes from it, or do some extra processing. For example:

```
def model_form_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save()
            # extract items from instance
            return # ...
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
    return render(request, 'src/model_form_upload.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

You can thus obtain the `id` of the instance in the form with `instance.pk`.

Alternatively, you can also use `form.instance` to get access to the instance the `Form` creates/modifies.